# HTML5 How to put background color in an article tag

Tags: html, article

i want to learn how to create an article with he header background for example

```
<article>
   <h1 background-color: green;> Title </h1> 
</article>
```

I want to know how to create an article post. btw im learing wordpress and i should need to have this done in code level.

Answer (score 2):

You need to place your style in a `style` attribute:

```
<article>
   <h1 style="background-color: green;"> Title </h1> 
</article>
```

Or

```
<article style="background-color: green;">
   <h1> Title </h1> 
</article>
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried: ...?

```
<article>
   <h1 style="background-color: green"> Title </h1> 
</article>
```

Answer (score 1):

it should be

```
<article>
   <h1 style='background-color: green;' > Title </h1> 
</article>
```

please go to this website
https://www.w3schools.com/html/default.asp
and learn THE `HTML`